# Datetime-local type in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb

I'm trying to define a trip(trajet) model schema, I want to know what will be the mongodb type for my field "date" since the form's input in my frontend is datetime-loca, I want the user to select date and time for his trip.

I've tried so many solutions, but they caused errors because of datatype that deosn't match between my schema definition and my frontend datatype requirement, this is how I've defined the type of "date" field in my schema:

```
date: {
        type: Date,
        required: [true, "Ajouter la date de départ"],
    },
```

and this is the input that I use in my frontend to insert data:

```
 <label htmlFor='date'>Date et heure : </label>
 <input type="datetime-local" className='form-control' name="date" id='date' placeholder='date de départ...'
```

Comment: The value of a datetime-local input is string, how are you converting that to the date type required by the schema?